# Health + Shield bar

Tags: java

So i'm trying to make a health + shield bar in my game. If you have ever played League of Legends or Heroes of the Storm, i'm trying to create a health and shield bar that works like that. if not, I  have some images for you:

(stackoverflow will not let me post more than 2 links, so just imagine a full health bar :) )

The first example is just the normal health bar displaying health. I got this to work fine by multiplying the percentage health (health/maxHealth) and multiplying that number by the length of the health bar (51)

[image]

This second example shows how the health and shield should look when the player is at full health. This is working fine too.

[image]

My problem comes here, when the player is not at full health. as you can see, in the first picture, Kalista has around 550 health. Then as she gains the shield, her health bar goes to around 850 total and the 300 health shield is grey. Then once she's taken damage to around 300 health, the 300 health shield is no longer compressed like when it was in the 850 health. My HUD health bar works until this point. Even when the health bar is not at its full capacity, it tries to compress the shield and health into what just the health bar was.

Here's my current code:

```
package net.masterzach32.sidescroller.assets.gfx;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import net.masterzach32.sidescroller.assets.Assets;
import net.masterzach32.sidescroller.entity.EntityPlayer;
import net.masterzach32.sidescroller.util.LogHelper;

public class HUD {

private EntityPlayer player;

private BufferedImage image;
private Font font;

double b0 = 31, b1 = 20, hx = 31, mx = 20;

public HUD(EntityPlayer p) {
    player = p;
    try {
        image = Assets.getImageAsset("hud");

        font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 14);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void render(Graphics2D g) {
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 15, null);

    double h0 = player.getHealth() / player.getMaxHealth();
    double h1 = h0 * hx;
    double m0 = player.getShield() / player.getMaxShield();
    double m1 = m0 * mx;

    if((int) (h1 + m1) <= hx + mx) {
        int f = (int) (mx - m1);
        h1 += f;
    }

    LogHelper.logInfo("" + (int) (h1 + m1));
    if(h1 >= b0) b0 = h1;
    if(h1 < b0) b0 -= .7;
    if(m1 >= b1) b1 = m1;
    if(m1 < b1) b1 -= .7;

    // health bar
    g.setColor(new Color(200, 0, 0));
    g.fillRect(17, 18, (int) b0, 13);
    g.setColor(new Color(0, 170, 0));
    g.fillRect(17, 18, (int) h1, 13);
    // mana bar
    g.setColor(new Color(200, 0, 0));
    g.fillRect((int) (17 + b0), 18, (int) b1, 13);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect((int) (17 + h1), 18, (int) m1, 13);

    g.setFont(font);
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    if(player.getOrbCurrentCd() > 0) g.drawString("" + (player.getOrbCurrentCd() / 60 + 1), 0, 12);
    else g.drawString("" + (player.getOrbCurrentCd() / 60), 0, 12);
    g.drawString(player.getLevel() + " - " + (int) player.getExp() + "/" + (int) player.getMaxExp(), 1, 70);
    g.setFont(font);
    g.drawString((int) (player.getHealth()) + "/" + (int) (player.getMaxHealth()), 16, 29);
}
}
```

Comment: Just as a tip, use a game library or engine.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the problem you're having? Maybe add some screenshots of what you're actually seeing as well. I also don't see a `main`, so I assume it's not something [that can be run as is](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which is generally a requirement here.

Comment: You see Zach, the essential problem is that we can't run this ourselves to see the problem. So, you should explain very clearly how you are calculating the values for the health and shield. Even better would be a little stand-alone program to demonstrate the problem you're having. :D

Comment: You should also edit your question title. Most people wouldn't want to read   a question after seeing a title like that.